# Реализация UDP сервера с графическим интерфейсом

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, сокет, udp

Моя задача - разработать приложение, которое по протоколу *UDP* управляет микроконтроллером (отправляет и принимает информацию от него).
Я реализовал консольный *UDP* сервер и графический интерфейс через `tkinter`. Соединил их и успешно протестировал отправку, с приёмом возникли проблемы: программы висит при запуске, нет ожидаемого окна от `tkinter`.
Мой код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from socket import *
import sys

#Настариваем куда будем отправлять данные
host = '192.168.10.10'
port = 8888
addr = (host,port)


vstavit = "Ожидание"
# первый параметр socket_family может быть AF_INET или AF_UNIX
# второй параметр socket_type может быть SOCK_STREAM(для TCP) или SOCK_DGRAM(для UDP)
udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_socket.bind(('', 0))

window = Tk()
window.geometry('800x500')

#Выполняемое действие при нажатии
def clicked():
    data = str.encode("1")
    udp_socket.sendto(data, addr)



#Название програмы
window.title("Окно программы")



#Добавляем во второй столбец чтобы отображалось и то и то
btn = Button(window, text="Не нажимать!", bg="Green", fg="Black", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)

#Добавим изображение ИТЭФ
canvas = Canvas(window, height=100, width=75)
img = PhotoImage(file = 'd:/PyCharmProgect/ITEF1.PNG')
image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw',image=img)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=6)
canvas.place(x=650, y=0)

i = 0

while True:
    data1, addr = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)  # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    vstavit = data1
    if not data1:
        udp_socket.close()
udp_socket.close()


#Текстовое поле для приема UDP клиента
txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=50, height=10)
txt.insert(INSERT, vstavit)
txt.grid(column=0, row=0)




#Бесконечный цикл, ждет взаимодействия с пользователем
window.mainloop()
```

Предположительное проблемное место -
`data1, addr = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)  # buffer size is 1024 bytes`
В режиме проверки все слетает на этой строчке.
Буду рад услышать ваши версии происходящего и советы о реализации данной задачи. Не судите строго, я новичок.

Comment: На данный момент я вынужден поставить тревогу "Невежливый или оскорбительный" на данный вопрос из-за присутствия нецензурной лексики. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой вопрос. - из очереди проверок

Comment: @Стас я предложил [поправку с улучшением вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/591600)

Comment: @0dminnimda спасибо!  Удалю тревогу как только правку примут

Comment: @Женя Соловьёв, вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем! Будьте дружелюбны и не забывайте про [нормы поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: @Стас правку приняли, вот и славно!

Comment: @0dminnimda Спасибо большое за поправку, буду более внимательным и кратким